# Como atualizar uma função do helper com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Olá, preciso de ajuda que deu um nó na cabeça, eu estou trabalhando com codeigniter, criei três funções no meu helper consultando o banco de dados, e exibo um resultado em divs com as quantidades de registros, eu chamo essas três funções do helper em todos os controles, só que agora preciso utilizar ajax para atualizar essas funções em tempo real, ai que travei, porque não sei como chamar essas funções do helper para ser atualizadas em tempo real. Se puderem me ajudar me dando uma luz, agradeço. Meu código está assim:

meu helper chamado: funcao_helper:

```
 function np()
       {
            // Obter uma referência ao objeto do controlador
            $CI = get_instance();
            //carrega o banco de dados
            $CI->load->model('dashboard_model');

            $np = $CI->dashboard_model->contarNotasPendentes();

           return $np;//retorna a quantidade de registros
       }

       function vf()
       {
            // Obter uma referência ao objeto do controlador
            $CI = get_instance();
            //carrega o banco de dados
            $CI->load->model('dashboard_model');
            $vf =  $CI->dashboard_model->contarVendasFuncionarios();

           return $vf; //retorna a quantidade de registros
       }

       function pd()
       {
            // Obter uma referência ao objeto do controlador
            $CI = get_instance();
           //carrega o banco de dados
            $CI->load->model('dashboard_model');
            $pd =  $CI->dashboard_model->contarNovosPedidos();

           return $pd; //retorna a quantidade de registros
       }
```

Meu controller Principal:

```
class Principal extends CI_Controller {
    
    public function index()
    {           
          //Notificações gerais do painel
          $data['np'] = np();//contar NF pendentes 
          $data['pd'] = pd();//contar os pedidos novos
          $data['vf'] = vf();//contar vendas 
          $total =  pd() + vf() + np();//somar todos
          $data['total'] =  $total;//exibir o valor total

          $this->load->view('admin/template/home', $data);
    }
    
}
```

Minha view:

```
<!--Aqui exibo os resultados nas divs-->
 <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge"><?php if (isset($total))  { if($total != "0")  {   echo $total; } } ?></span>
        </a>
           
          if($pd != "0")  { ?>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="dropdown-item">
            <?php echo $pd ?> Novo Pedido
          </a>
          <?php } ?>
               
          if($vf != "0")  { ?>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('') ?>" class="dropdown-item">
            <?php  echo $vf; ?> Venda
          </a>
          <?php  } ?>

          if($np != "0")  { ?>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <?php echo $np ?> Nf Pendente
          </a>
          <?php } ?>
```

Dai tentei um ajax assim pra atualizar a função pd:

```
<script>
 var visualizarPedido = setInterval(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url('principal/index/pd') ?>",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $("#dropdown-item").text(html);
                        },
                });
            },2000)
</script>
```

Mas até agora nada, se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: No console apresenta algum erro?

Comment: Não, mas não exibe nada.

Comment: Acho interessante ativar os erros php `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` no começo do código, pode ser que esteja desabilitado no servidor

Comment: agora ele apareceu no console no javascript  404 Page Not FoundThe page you requested was not found., acho que não está achando meu helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom depois de mto quebrar a cabeça conseguir resolver, vou deixar minha resposta caso alguém precise no futuro.

```
//Atualizar Notificações de Pedidos
        var atualizaNotificacaoPedido = function (tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos) {
          
              $.ajax({
                  type:"GET",
                  url:"http://[::1]/principal/pedido", 
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (resposta){
   
                    if (resposta.erro == 0) {
                  
                       $('.pd').html(resposta.listar_servico);
                       setTimeout(function() { atualizaNotificacaoPedido(tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos); }, tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos * 40000);
                       
                    } else{
   
                       alert('Erro ao trazer serviços');
                       setTimeout(function() { atualizaNotificacaoPedido(tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos); }, tempoParaChecarNovamenteEmSegundos * 40000);
                    }
   
                  },
                  error:function(){
                      console.log(resposta);
                      alert('Erro ao trazer serviços.');
                  }
             });
      }
       
      atualizaNotificacaoPedido(40000);
```

Dai no meu controller criei uma reposta em json para puxar meu select do banco ficando assim:

```
 public function pedido()
    {
        $listar_servico = $this->dashboard_model->contarNovosPedidos();
        
        if ($listar_servico) {  
          
                $retorno['erro'] = 0;
                $retorno['msg']  = 'Pedido consultado com sucesso';
                $retorno['listar_servico']  = $listar_servico;

                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($retorno);
                exit;

            } else {

                $retorno['erro'] = 60;
                $retorno['msg']  = 'Erro';

                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($retorno);
                exit;
        }

    }
```

E minha view ficou assim:

```
 if($pd != "0")  { ?>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>" class="dropdown-item">
            <span class="pd" id="pd"></span> Novo Pedido
          </a>
      <?php } ?>
```

A única coisa que ficou ainda desregulada para mim é controlar o tempo no ajax que está mto rapido, já tentei colocar, 40000 e ainda assim fica mto rapido, mas se eu conseguir ajustar arrumo aqui tb. vlw